# Ruby Bundle install/update after new Mavericks update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems, osx-mavericks

I am trying to run bundle install / bundle update after my update to Mavericks on my Mac, but I get the following error. Any ideas?

I am using RVM to manage everything.

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Using rake (10.1.0) 
Using i18n (0.6.5) 
Using multi_json (1.8.2) 
Using activesupport (3.2.1) 
Using builder (3.0.4) 
Using activemodel (3.2.1) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.4) 
Using rack (1.4.5) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using hike (1.2.3) 
Using tilt (1.4.1) 
Using sprockets (2.1.3) 
Using actionpack (3.2.1) 
Using mime-types (1.25) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.15) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.1) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.38) 
Using activerecord (3.2.1) 
Using activeresource (3.2.1) 
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3) 
Using execjs (2.0.2) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.3) 
Using json (1.8.1) 
Using rdoc (3.12.2) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.2.1) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Using jquery-rails (3.0.4) 
Installing pg (0.17.0) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/robin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb 

checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/robin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/robin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/pg-0.17.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/robin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/pg-0.17.0/ext/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

So yes, I cannot figure out the problem. Am I suppose to download PostgreSQL gem? I already got the command line tools from XCode.

Comment: Personally I prefer to use the PostgresApp for mac.  http://postgresapp.com/

Comment: Are you using homebrew to install postgresql?  Try `brew reinstall postgresql` then `bundle install`...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Homebrew, this does the trick:

- xcode-select --install
- brew update
- brew reinstall / install postgresql

Then you will be able to install pg from Gemfile

Answer (score 0):

For those of you reading this, and on Mavericks with Xcode 5, then you'll have to get the command line tools for Xcode 5 in order to get the gem.  Running `xcode-select --install` may fail to retrieve the command line tools for the brand-new Xcode.  Go to the [Apple Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/downloads), and then to Downloads.   You may have to sign up as an Apple Developer.  Download the:  *Command Line Tools (OSX Mavericks) for Xcode - Late October*.

Also, I recommend using [Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/).  Download that also.  Uninstall and remove any previous installations of Postgres if you have them lurking around in your system.  After installation, ensure that you can run `psql` from command-line by calling it, or calling `which psql`.  You should have it if you've installed Postgres at all.  If you can't call it, you may need to add it to your PATH variable, like so:

`PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"`

(On my system, I downloaded the latest Postgres.app, so my path variable was:

`PATH="/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"`

Put that in your .bash_profile so you always have access to it in the terminal.  For a *great* reference on setting up Postgres on Mac, Linux, or Windows, see [this documentation from Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup).

Finally, you *should* be able to get the gem:

`gem install pg`

For those of you switching over from Sqlite to Postgres, I also recommend [this documentation from Heroku as well](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3).